# showing ranks on yaxis in highchart in a manner that 1 is best and 50 is worst

Tags: highcharts

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/MybCM/26/) a sample in `highcharts` for what exactly i need to create. The issue i am facing is the blue color should be in the `area` chart series, but highchart is applying the color at the top (outside the series). I apologize if i am not able to explain the issue correctly.

This happens when i use `reversed: true,` in `yAxis`.

Please help or let me know if you need me to explain the issue in different words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reverse the axis, the data reverses as well, to match.

I would probably do this by using negative values as the axis min/max, and the data points.

Then, in the axis label formatter, return the absolute value (removing the '-').

```
labels: {
    formatter: function() {
        return Math.abs(this.value);   
    }
}
```

You can use the same formatting method to fix the tool tips, data labels, and anything else that might need it.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/MybCM/27/